# MongoDB or couchDB for Social Networking websites?

Tags: mongodb, social-networking, nosql

Im so impressed with nosql DB's and really wish to use MongoDB for my application,

But i feel like its limited for joins [joining 3 or 4 tables], union kinda things.

Is it possible to use MongoDB for social networking sites like Tagged,FB etc..

no idea about couchDB... any one guide me through,

Thanks,

Edvin

Comment: Try looking into graph databases. I'm working on a hybrid approach that uses Mongo to store more static data like profiles, but I'm using a graph databases (as opposed to Mongo's dbRef) to store relationships. I would highly suggest Mongo (great community) for a document db. For graph databases, I really like Neo4j. The only other graph database I looked at was Sones, but I was disappointed in the lack of documentation or much of a community. Neo4j, by the way, also has an excellent community.

Comment: You might find this useful regarding the limitations of using a document database (not just Mongo) for a social network application:

http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2013/11/11/why-you-should-never-use-mongodb/

Answer (score 4):

You can use MongoDB for any application, of course. However, if you're concerned about lack of ability to do things like joins then you should seriously consider sticking with SQL based solutions.

MongoDB is not a relational database management system. Thinking in terms of joins and other common relational concepts is not something that's particularly well suited for noSQL. MongoDB is substantially more "hybrid" or "SQLish" in the sense that it will allow you to do some form of cross document querying, but in practice it should be avoided in preference to rethinking the way you model your data.

The most common (and best) practice in most situations for a document-oriented database like MongoDB is to simply embed the documents. There's a nice [write up on the mongo site about schema design](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design) to help you think about the difference between embedding and referencing documents.

noSQL can be a very powerful tool, but you should think carefully about how your data fits the noSQL model before implementing. And, make sure you think through the pros and cons of using one database solution over another.

Comment: +1 I would add that social and indeed *many* web applications are not as "relational" as you might think. That is why Mongo and NoSQL have become successful recently. It is one step back and two steps forward.

Answer (score 1):

Yes why not, it can be clustered or replicated with other datacenters.

And its very fast.. only you if you want to use auto incremental id's you have to use something like twitters snowflake..

For the joins you can use data models to create the join with 3 or 4 queries

Comment: Can i have any data model for larger application from your application